# No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "IsChecked", or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The control I created doesn't have an IsChecked property, so I created it, and when I try to bind to it, I get this error. Can you tell me where is wrong?

```
 <Ctrl:CtrlImageToggleButton
                                            x:Name="xEnablePV"
                                            Grid.Row="7"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding EnablePV}"
                                            ToggleOffImageSource="btn_off.png"
                                            ToggleOnImageSource="btn_on.png" />



   public class CtrlImageToggleButton : ImageButton
        {
            private bool bCheck = false;
            public delegate void eStatusChanged();
            public event eStatusChanged event_StatusChanged;
                      
            public bool IsChecked 
            {
                get
                {
                    return bCheck;
                }
                set
                {
                    bCheck = value;
                    SetValue(IsCheckedProPerty, value);
    
                    if (this.event_StatusChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.event_StatusChanged();
                    }
                }       
            }
    
    
            public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProPerty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                              propertyName: "IsCheckedProPerty",
                                                              returnType: typeof(bool),
                                                              declaringType: typeof(CtrlImageToggleButton),
                                                              defaultValue: false,
                                                              defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                              propertyChanged: IsCheckedProPertyChanged);
    
            private static void IsCheckedProPertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
            {
                (bindable as CtrlImageToggleButton).IsChecked = (bool)newValue;
            }       
        }
    }
```

오류  XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "IsChecked", or mismatching type between value and property.  POP D:\ProgramSrc\POP Renewal\POP\POP\Component\Spectrum\Spectrum_OptionPage.xaml   196

Comment: Why do you have a random capital “P” in the middle of “IsCheckedProPerty”?  That breaks the naming convention for Bindable properties

Comment: Could you please elaborate?
Are you saying it should be changed to IsCheckedproperty?

Comment: When I changed it to IsCheckedProperty, it worked normally. I didn't know there was a naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fixed naming convention for Bindable properties that you have to follow so your property name should be something like shown below:

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                              propertyName: nameof(IsChecked),
                                              returnType: typeof(bool),
                                              declaringType: typeof(CtrlImageToggleButton),
                                              defaultValue: false,
                                              defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                              propertyChanged: IsCheckedPropertyChanged);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73903307/xfc0009no-property-bindableproperty-or-event-found-for-selectitem-or-misma

Can you see the error in this case too?

This is a slightly different example. And follow the naming convention.

Comment: @정영훈 I have added a much detailed answer hope that helps you out :)