# XFC0009 No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "SelectItem", or mismatching type between value and property

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

```
<Ctrl:CtrlPickerButton
                                            x:Name="xEditSpeed"
                                            Grid.Row="5"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Padding="0,10,0,10"
                                            SelectItem="{Binding Speed}" />
```

*************** CtrlPickerButton.xaml ****************

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="POP.Controls.CtrlPickerButton"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:Ctrl="clr-namespace:POP.Controls"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">


    <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame
            Padding="1"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorBorder000}"
            CornerRadius="0"
            HasShadow="False"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Frame
                Padding="0"
                CornerRadius="0"
                HasShadow="false">

                <Ctrl:PickerCommon
                    x:Name="xPicker"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    TextColor="{DynamicResource ColorText000}"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            </Frame>
        </Frame>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

*************** CtrlPickerButton.cs ****************
public partial class CtrlPickerButton : ContentView
{
public CtrlPickerButton()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
        public int SelectItem
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(ItemChangedProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemChangedProperty, value);
                xPicker.SelectedIndex = value;
            }
        }


        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemChangedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                          propertyName: nameof(SelectItem),
                                                          returnType: typeof(int),
                                                          declaringType: typeof(CtrlPickerButton),
                                                          defaultValue: 1,
                                                          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                          propertyChanged: SelectedItemProPertyChanged);

        private static void SelectedItemProPertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            (bindable as CtrlPickerButton).SelectItem = (int)newValue;
        }
    }
```

The binding property naming convention was followed.
But I get a Missmatching error.

What went wrong?

Comment: Your bindable property is named “ItemChangedProperty”, not “SelectItemProperty”

Comment: I changed it to ItemChangedProperty but the result is the same.

Comment: public int SelectItem
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(ItemChangedProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemChangedProperty, value);
                xPicker.SelectedIndex = value;
            }
        }

Comment: public static readonly BindableProperty ItemChangedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
             propertyName: "ItemChangedProperty",
            returnType: typeof(int),
            declaringType: typeof(CtrlPickerButton),
          defaultValue: 1,
         defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
          propertyChanged: ItemChangedProPertyChanged);

        private static void ItemChangedProPertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            (bindable as CtrlPickerButton).SelectItem = (int)newValue;
        }

Comment: I don't know how to upload the code sorry

Comment: [edit] your question, don’t stuff code in the comments.  And you are doing the exact **opposite** of what you should be doing.  See Freakyalis answer below for more detail

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is that there is a Naming convention that you need to follow when you create a Bindable property.

- Your Property has a name that follows CamelCase. Eg below:

  ```
  public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
  ```
- Create your Bindable part for your property:

  ```
  public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                      propertyName: nameof(SelectedItem),
                                                      returnType: typeof(int),
                                                      declaringType: typeof(CtrlPickerButton),
                                                      defaultValue: 1,
                                                      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
                                                      propertyChanged: SelectedItemProPertyChanged);
  ```
- Focus on how the name of your BindableProperty's name is your PropertyName+ the word Property so **"SelectedItemProperty"**, Now the first value that you need to pass in your Create method is the name of your property i.e. **"SelectedItem"**
- Now your property's getter and setter change to update based on our Bindable property:

  ```
    public int SelectedItem
    {
        get =>(int)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
    }
  ```

More detailed information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-bindable-property

Hope this helps

Good luck!

Comment: public int SelectIedtem
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItemProperty , value);
                xPicker.SelectedIndex = value;
            }
        }

Thank you so much for your kind explanation I did the way you said but the error is the same

Comment: 'public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty  = BindableProperty.Create(
      propertyName: nameof(SelectIedtem),
      returnType: typeof(int),
      declaringType: typeof(CtrlPickerButton),
      defaultValue: 1,
      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
      propertyChanged: SelectedItemProPertyChanged);

        private static void SelectedItemProPertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            (bindable as CtrlPickerButton).SelectIedtem = (int)newValue;
        }'

Comment: <Ctrl:CtrlPickerButton
                                            x:Name="xEditSpeed"
                                            Grid.Row="5"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Padding="0,10,0,10"
                                            SelectIedtem="{Binding Speed}" />

Comment: @정영훈 I will need to see your full View and ViewModel to help you further, Also edit your question to add these things instead of comments